# How to add shadow to the tags typed in the input area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I am developing a Q&A website like **stackoverflow.com**. But I am confused when I tried to implement the **shadow-style** while adding tags to the question by typing the tags into a HTML <input> area. I want to know which tools should I use to make each tag in my <input> area shadowed because CSS style is useless in the <input> area,and how to do it?

A simple example is listed below and this is just the tag inputing area of stackoverflow:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMMVT.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your current working code please

Comment: @Xiangyi Meng  don't forget to tick it => if answer is usefull

Comment: Just have a look at the Example I added in the question... And you will know what I want... Thanks T_T

Comment: @Xiangyi Meng  check now,I'm updated

Comment: Are you using [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify)?

Comment: @vsync Great answer. Tagify totally satisfy my demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of the answerer. According to the hint from @vsync. I use [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) to implement my demand. That plugin totally satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **box-shadow:inset** for this purpose.
if you want to give shadow for the text use **text-shadow**

for more check this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/).
I'm added an example below.

```css
input{
  box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 5px #000;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 5px green;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:400;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just want to make my tags inside the input area shadowed... Not the input box itself... Any suggestion else?

Comment: Wow that's approach my destination...Thx u...  But could I make my tag-input area like that in stackoverflow? Maybe that's kinda difficult for me...:(

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
  #yourid{
  box-shadow:inset 0px 5px 5px #666666;
  }
</style>
<input type="text" id="yourid">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too... But I just want to make my tags inside the input area shadowed... Not the input box itself... Any suggestion else?

Answer (score 0):

use `text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);`

Answer (score 0):

you need `text-shadow` for it :

```
input{
     color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}
```

also look here for [some generators](http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/) to help you out